# "Loading" issue with some cells. My Google Spreadsheet is not updating and the google apps script doesn't work properly

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have a questionnaire with Google Form on my site. Whenever an user fill out the questionnaire, its answers are used in a spreadsheet to evaluate something. The answers are stored properly by the spreadsheet. The SS does some calculations and in a different sheet, called "Report", I store the result. My GS script sends an email to the user with its result. I've set an activator every 30 minutes to run the sendEmail function. This morning the script doesn't work because the result in the spreadsheet were not evaluated. Te return is "#Name?" for the result cell.

How is it possible to keep updated the spreadsheet? At the beginning of the function I do:

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmail() {
  //TO DO: Active Sheet Check
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Report');
```

Is there some operation to update the ss: basically to run all the mathematical operation?
Do I need to deploy the script?

Comment: maybe that's what you're looking for [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=ru#flush())

Comment: If the solution proposed by @Sergey doesn't help you, please consider sharing your Spreadsheet and you full script in order to give you some assistance.

Comment: Hi Guys! Thank you for your time. I cannot share the entire script o spreadsheet. I try to explain better my issue. 
I have a questionnaire for risk profiling. When the user fills out the questionnaire I have a Google Sheet with multiple sheets where I do some mathematical operation on its answer which exploit Google Sheet's pre-built operations and some custom function developed by me. I have another function which is activated every 30 minutes to send the result of the profiling operation to the compiler. 
However most of the time the cells where I store the results are in "Loading" so the

Comment: [continue] so the return is just "#Name?" which is treated as Error in my script. I would like to know if there is a way to force the spreadsheet to run all the operations before running the function to send email with the result. Or at least if there are some "Best Practices" to avoid SLOW LOADING for some cells.

Comment: Hi. Have you check the answer proposed by @Sergey? Add `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before getting the values that are not calculated yet. By the way, it would be difficult to help you without a deeper look at your problem. Could you make a simple version of your spreadsheet or provide some reproduction steps in order to get the same error as you? `#Name` error means that a function is misspelled or that a range is not defined, and probably the problem is within your code or your calculations.